# How to edit specific words on exe program

Tags: c, windows, exe

Is it possible to change some words on interface of .exe program? i've tried to change some words with notepad++ but the icon of the .exe changes and i was not able to run the program unless i undo the changes i've made.

Comment: You probably want [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

Comment: You could try a hex editor, often a plugin in a programmer's editor like NotePad++.

Comment: Easy -- modify the source, and re-build ;) A resource editor will be nicer if the text in question was provided by the developer in the form of resources -- probably there's no way to tell without checking. Otherwise, binary/hex editing is probably the only way to go. If the text is ASCII/UTF-8 it's probably not too nasty, but with any other multi-byte encoding you'll likely struggle to find the text, and then to edit it properly.

Comment: Try not to change the length of the strings and you should be fine even with NotePad++

Comment: Also some stuff like strings in the menu, dialogues etc might not even be in the exe. Could be a part of a system dll.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achive. Curiosity? Be more specific and you are likely to get better answers. Read this [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because does not have anything in common with the programming.& C language. Another tag spam

Comment: @MichaelWalz i have .exe program on its interface the first page when i run the program it show some words, i want to replace those words thats all, does that make sense?

Comment: @KeithZetterstrom I don't know if it makes sense, but [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) is definitely the thing you need.

Comment: *If* you have a binary file editor, this is straightforward.  The only difficulties are that (1) binary editors are unusual (you've probably never seen one), and (2) you must not move anything around.  So you can replace a string with one of exactly the same length, or you can make a string shorter if you're careful to leave padding so that nothing after it moves, but in general you can't make a string longer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this to edit anything with exe's or dll's but make sure you make backups of the exe before making changes because anything can go wrong: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Answer (score 1):

When editing Binary data, the best solution for me is always [hex-workshop](http://download.cnet.com/Hex-Workshop/3000-2352_4-10004918.html?part=dl-HexWorksh&subj=dl&tag=button).

But notice, you need to **really** understand what you are doing when editing binary data. If you just change one string to another, in high odds you will screw up things if you do not know what your are doing and what effect this change has.

Comment: is there any tutorial or instruction to change .exe interface some words? using hex workshop?

Comment: @KeithZetterstrom it's all about the format of compiled windows resources. A very vast subject.

Comment: @KeithZetterstrom Editing data is very simple, open your file with hex-workshop and you will see all the bytes in your file, and you can edit them. it is very intuitive.

Knowing what to edit is much more complex, as it is a much wider question. There are many different types of "bytes" in the binary file. Some are code, some are strings and some are relative jump tables (of course there are may other options)

Comment: @KeithZetterstrom Try explaining your problem more specifically (What exactly you want to edit) and it would be much easier to help you

Comment: i have .exe program i want to replace some words for example support email which written there

Comment: @Idan how can i get in touch with you? do u have fb / skype?

Comment: @KeithZetterstrom I am sorry but no. Did you manage to find the strings you want to change by opening the file in hex-workshop?

Comment: @Idan did installed hex-workshop but all igot is numbers i have no idea how to replace the words with these numbers

Comment: @Idan can u do that for me and i'll pay you i just need to change few words?

Comment: here my facebook add me fb.com/emadrashaydah